# Gravar quebra de linha do textarea no banco de dados

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, ajax

Tenho um `<textarea class="form-control" id="informacoes" name="informacoes" rows="3" placeholder="descreva aqui..."></textarea>` onde o usuário pode inserir informações diversas.

A informação é enviada via `ajax`:

```
function salvaFlor(){
  var myForm = document.getElementById('formflor');
  var form = new FormData(myForm);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "functions/salvarFlor.php",
    data: form,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'ok'){
        alert('Dados salvos com sucesso!');
        listaFlor();
      }else{
        alert(data);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

A questão é que, se o usuário pular de linha para organizar a informação, quando eu salvo no banco de dados `"insert into flor (informacoes) values ('".$informacoes."')";` as quebras de linha são perdidas...

Como fazer pra salvar os dados do `textarea` com as quebras de linha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) pra fazer isso. 
No seu método `salvarFlor` você pode fazer isso:
`$textArea = nl2br($stringTextArea);`